# Array weighted average only if row has data

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the below two columns of data and want to calculate the weighted average, with Column B being the weights. However, I would like to exclude from the calculation those weights for which there is no data in Column A, i.e. rows 2 and 8 below.

How can I do this straightforwardly?

The formula I am using is:

{=SUM(A2:A9*B2:B9)/SUM(B2:B13)}

The issue is that this automatically selects the entire column B, or put differently, all of the weights even if Column A doesn't always have data.

```
| Column A  | Column B|
-----------------------
| 158.3     |   59.3
|           |   1.5
| 166.5     |   7.1
| 150.7     |   8.1
| 151.5     |   4.0
| 182.8     |   6.7
| 111.2     |   5.6
|           |   0.2
```

Comment: Try this `=sumproduct(A:A,B:B)/100`

Comment: What would be your result manually for given data?

Comment: @harun24hr So by using the formula in my post, I get: 154.0175. However, this implicitly adds all weights, which is not what I want. By disregarding (deleting) the rows with no data in Column A, the result I get is 156.8509. This is the correct value, but it required me to manually delete rows without data in column A.

Comment: Your problem is not a formula error, but a logic error. You're getting 153.98 instead of 142.43 because your weigh% column doesn't add up to 100%. With your current values, 154 is the correct result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope following formula may work for you.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A2:A9,B2:B9)/SUMIF(A2:A9,">0",B2:B9)
```

Let me know what result it give you.

Comment: I thought about going this route, but decided not to in case a value in A was actually 0 or negative.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

The above uses the following formula.

```
=SUMPRODUCT($A$3:$A$10,$B$3:$B$10)/SUMPRODUCT($B$3:$B$10*($A$3:$A$10<>""))
```

Sumproduct performs array like operations.  As such avoid using full column references like C:C within the sumproduct function as it will cause excessive calculations.